# How can I remove this hidden keybinding in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Juno and this is the keybinding bound to Ctrl+Shift+B according to the preferences menu:

[image: Image of preferences Windows where only one function, Build All, is bound to Ctrl+Shift+B]

Yet when I hit Ctrl+Shift+B, Eclipse pops up this conflict dialog window in the lower right corner of the IDE:

[image: Image of dialog where both "Build All" and "Toggle Breakpoint" is assigned to Ctrl+Shift+B]

I've tried clearing and reassigning the "Toggle Breakpoint" function to no avail. I've also checked the "Toggle watch" function but that is not the problem. I've also tried restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

I've had a hidden key binding which I removed in [your-workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi as mentioned on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052758/hidden-keybindings

Problem for me was that the key binding was introduced through a plugin which I then uninstalled, but apparently the key binding was not fully uninstalled.

Comment: Great find! :-)